# How to set image on a imageview in webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview

Trying to change the profile image on the web view.
But when trying the updated image showing a crashed image.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('SelectedImage').src='"+profilePath+"';}) ();");
```

Comment: `profilePath` should be the absolute path to the image.

Comment: File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Android");
        uploadImageName = destination.getName();
        imagepath = destination.toString();
        MyProfileActivity.profilePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();    Yes, profile path is absolute one but unabe to change the image

Comment: if i use below code it will set on the whole web view.         String imagePath = "file:///"+profilePath;
            webView.loadUrl(imagePath);

Answer (score 0):

If `profilePath` is a Uri object, then you need to get the absolute path from the object. 
Use `File f = new File(profilePath.toString());`

Comment: Yes, profile path is absolute           File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Android");
        uploadImageName = destination.getName();
        imagepath = destination.toString();
        MyProfileActivity.profilePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        imagepath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        MyProfileActivity.profilePath = imagepath;